# Network from pandas dataframe with colours

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I would need to create a network using the following data

```
String        List1                           
string1 [string3, string2, string20, string4]   
string2 [string100, string1, string4]
string3 [string1, string80, string2]
string4 [string13, string28, string12, string16]
string5 [string3, string8, string12, string6]
string6 []
```

with indirect links which shows links among the variables/nodes.
So, for example, string1 is linked with string3, string2, string30, string4. String2 is linked with string100, string1 and string4, and so on.

I have tried to use Networkx

```
import itertools.combinations as comb

edges = set()
for col in df:
    for _, data in df.groupby(col):
        edges.update(comb(data.index, 2))

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df.index)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

but it does not do what I would expect as output.

Comment: what do you expect as output?

Comment: Hi warped. I would like to create a graph where the nodes are my strings (it is just a label) and links between them if there is relationships (like in the list of bullets). Colours would be the link colours, but it is secondary. I am not able to create the graph with he code that I wrote in my post

Comment: Ok, what does df look like?

Comment: I have tried to rewrite in a simple way what I am trying to do. I think I should explode the dataset in order to create the network. Right now, my dataset looks like in the post. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indeed you should use `df.explode`. `networkx`has a function that you can feed the exploded df into directly:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.explode('List1'), source='String', target='List1')
```

That said, the way you construct the dataframe (i.e. lists as cell entries) causes a lot of headaches, so it is best avoided.